# Figuring out which element triggered request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working on a large project developed by 5 people.
The problem is that every time I load a particular page, I get a stray POST request along with the GET request for the page. The page contains no forms though a fair amount a jquery has been used.

```
Started POST "/my_profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-06 21:34:23 +0530
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/my_profile"):
```

Is there a way to find out which element or script triggered this POST request other than going through the entire code which is divided into 20 partials and 2 javascripts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, check out the Firebug plugin. The net panel will allow you to easily track down any POST / GET requests for a given page load.

Answer (score 1):

You might try `[binding_of_caller][1]`, `caller` or possibly `[set_trace_func][2]`.

[Dzone Snippets](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2787) offers a robust way of using `caller`:

```
def caller_method_name
    parse_caller(caller(2).first).last
end

def parse_caller(at)
    if /^(.+?):(\d+)(?::in `(.*)')?/ =~ at
        file = Regexp.last_match[1]
        line = Regexp.last_match[2].to_i
        method = Regexp.last_match[3]
        [file, line, method]
    end
end
```

Or you could do `caller.inspect` and just look at the raw output.

Binding_of_caller is a bit more involved and may be overkill for what you want but check it out if `caller` is not what you need. Same with `set_trace_func`.